# android studio build error debug-unaligned.apk path not found

Tags: android, build, android-studio, apk

Last night I updated my android studio to 0.5.3 and since than i am getting this error message whenever I am trying to generate a signed-apk. It does not occur when I am just running the project over android studio.

I tried rebuilding, cleaning project, restarting android-studio, reimporting the project, no success. I am pretty desperate right now

EDIT: i found out that actually debug-unaligned is not generated... But why is that? And why do i need to generate it if i am just trying to sign the app

Comment: I get the same problem when I run "Make Project". It doesn't actually bother building an apk any more. I've got no idea why as I've never had the slightest clue what gradle does, what the various tasks it runs are, where the configuration for these tasks is, or anything else. I have to run gradle build to get the apk to build but don't know why "Make Project" doesn't do this any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 0.5.3, we tried to speed up the build process by not having it do a full build to an APK except when it needs to, but we missed some cases where it needs to.

You can follow progress in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67948 but in the meantime you can work around it by running the `assembleRelease` task, either from the command line or from the Gradle tasks view:

[image: Gradle tasks view showing assembleRelease task]