# Generating Signed APK error : Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Unable to generate the signed apk,
its being halted in the middle and below are the two alerts being showed up.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this ??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735176/android-studio-build-error-debug-unaligned-apk-path-not-found/22767533#22767533