# Android simple deployment from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build

I spent a while building an app for Android using Android Studio, and now I want to be able to pick up the the apk and send it to my client. My app does not need to get on the google appstore (PlayStore) because it is not a public app. It is designed only for my customer.

Is there no way of doing the deployment (getting the apk) simply by clicking on some (Build) buttons?

I searched the web and found a link from Google that gives me instructions as long as 4-6 pages of things to do. This is insane. I just want to compile my app and use it. I do not want to sign up to be a senator, I do not want to do tricks or do compilations by hand and stuff like that. Is it that hard to make a wizard inside the IDE that asks you and runs the necessary tasks for me?

I used Eclipse previously and I remember I was able to do that from inside the Eclipse IDE

Do you understand my problem?

**Is there a SIMPLE way of obtaining the apk of my app so I can send it to my customer?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your definition of "simple" is, but going to Build in the menubar and using "Generate Signed APK..." will do just that. You might have to set up your keys and whatnot, but nothing terribly complicated on the command line or anything, if that's what you're looking to avoid.

Comment: If you're using Android Studio 0.5.3, be aware of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735176/android-studio-build-error-debug-unaligned-apk-path-not-found

Comment: I finally got to see the Generate Signed APK in the build menu, after trying everything else. This is what I was looking for. By "simple" I meant a wizard, that allows me to stop wasting time doing manual java stuff in order to obtain a final apk. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to get an apk, is going to

```
...\AndroidStudio\[YOUR_PROYECT]\app\build\apk
```

and there you will find the apk that Android Studio generate and send to the mobile when you debug the app

Comment: Yeah, if you don't care if the apk is signed, this is an even better answer than mine, in that you don't have to do anything but grab the file.

Comment: I wanted to do that from the start but in that folder there was a apk file that sounded "not-cool", something like "blah-development-blah.apk" So I did not go that way since it seemed like not the final-final version.

Comment: Thank you all for your fast answers. I am in a real hurry so that helped me a lot.

Comment: That apk is not a release signed version, but it is a complete and working apk, since it is  the exact one that is installed in the phone when you debug the app.